# Changing an hex value in a specific address

Tags: c#, assembly, hex, byte

I have this [image: Address] address in a .exe file, I want to do a C# Windows Form Application that let me write a new number in the address hex part, I mean it is **"C0/EA/03"**, I want to change the **"03"** to the number I write in my application and save the change. Is that possible? If it is, please help me on how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

For being more specific, I want to do this:

-**example(not valid, just a example)**-

[image]

so when i click the button the 03 in the address I show before will be now FF (255 hex).

Comment: Can't you just use a HEX Editor..

Comment: Does C# not support reading and writing data from and to files???

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a screenshot from OllyDbg, is this the case? Next question is do you want to do this at runtime (inject) or in the static exe file (patch)?

To patch the file, you need to figure out the actual offset in the exe file of that particular byte. Doing so requires identifying the text section of the PE file, going to the base address of the text section, then offsetting into the text section. To get the offset, you need to use a disassembler, like Olly or ndisasm. Find the `shr dl,3` instruction, then calculate that instruction's offset from the base of the loaded text section. Remember that the loaded virtual addresses are not the same as the addresses in the file. 0x538695 is probably a loaded virtual address, but hard to tell from your problem description (I am guessing it is a virtual address because it looks like Olly's font). Anyway, add that offset to the base of the text section in the PE EXE file, and you are all set.

This is probably easier done with a tool like LordPE.

http://www.tech-juice.org/2011/02/21/portable-executable-converting-rva-to-file-offset-and-back/

Comment: Ty sir, yes it is OllyDbg, what I was planning to do is something like this http://screensnapr.com/e/tHqBBC.jpg so when i click the button the 03 in the address I show before will be now FF (255 hex).

Comment: Well then read up on RVA to file offset conversion that I linked and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: @JaggedO'Neill
Ikr, it was just a non-valid example.